# Closest Numbers

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge, sorting

Online coding challenge [Hacker Rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/closest-numbers).

Given a list of unsorted integers, find the pair of elements that have the smallest absolute difference between them? If there are multiple pairs, find them all.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    
    private static List<Integer> solve(int []arr) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int diff = arr[i + 1] - arr[i];
            if (diff < min) {
                min = diff;
                list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(arr[i]);
                list.add(arr[i + 1]);
            }
            else if (diff == min) {
                list.add(arr[i]);
                list.add(arr[i + 1]);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = s.nextInt();
        int []arr = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            arr[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        List<Integer> result = solve(arr);
        for (int n : result) {
            System.out.print(n + " ");   
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

I would definitely have chosen better names in actual scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is something with objects:

Model:

```
static class Pair {
    int x, y;

    public Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    int diff() {
        return y - x;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  x + " " + y + " ";
    }


}
```

controller:

```
private static List<Pair> solve(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    TreeMap<Integer, List<Pair>> pairsByDiff = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        Pair pair = new Pair(arr[i - 1], arr[i]);
        List<Pair> sameDiffPairs = pairsByDiff.getOrDefault(pair.diff(), new ArrayList<>());
        sameDiffPairs.add(pair);
        pairsByDiff.put(pair.diff(), sameDiffPairs);
    }
    return pairsByDiff.firstEntry().getValue();
}
```

UI:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = s.nextInt();
        int []arr = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            arr[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        List<Pair> result = solve(arr);
        for (Pair n : result) {
            System.out.print(n);   
        }
}
```